# Find "A" in this equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

$$ \sqrt[3] {A-15√3} + \sqrt[3] {A+15√3} = 4 $$

Find "A" ?
The way of exponentiation took too much time, is there any easier method?

Comment: Are you sure you completed it? What value of $A$ did you find?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y$ be the numbers $(A\pm 15\sqrt 3)^{1/3}$ so that $x+y=4$. hen we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2A &=
x^3+y^3\\
&= (x+y)^3-3xy(x+y)
\\
&= 4^3-3xy\cdot 4
\\
&=64 - 3(A^2-675)^{1/3}\cdot 4\ .\text{ So:}
\\[3mm]
6^3(A^2-675)
&=(32-A)^3\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This gives us an equation in $A$, that we may solve (with bare hands or not).

```
sage: var('A');
sage: solve( (32 - A)^3 - 6^3*(A^2-675) == 0, A )
[A == -9*I*sqrt(19) - 73, A == 9*I*sqrt(19) - 73, A == 26]
```

OK, $26$ is a solution (obtained with bare hands or not), the only real solution.

---

**LATER EDIT:**
It seems that there is a real interest in finding solutions with bare hands. Let us do this  explicitly. The equation of degree three in $A$,
$$
(A-32)^3+6^3(A^2-675)
=0
$$
becomes after expanding:
$$
A^{3} + 120 \, A^{2} + 3072 \, A - 178568 = 0\ .
$$
To have smaller coefficients it is humanly useful to observe that $2|120$, $4|3072$, $8|178568$, so we may substitute $A=2B$, and get the equation in $B$:
$$
h(B):=
B^3 + 60B^2 + 768B - 22321 = 0\ .
$$
If this equation has **rational** solutions (as psychologically expected in human problems), then any rational solution is of the form $\pm p/q$, where $p$ divides the free coefficient $-22321=13 \cdot 17 \cdot 101$, and $q$ divides the principal coefficient (of $B^3$), which is one. So we compute  $h(0)<0$, expect a positive solution, and *try* the values $1, 13, 17, 13\cdot 17, 101, 13\cdot 101,\dots$ and note immediately that $h(100) >0$, so only $1,13,17$ may have a chance. The $1$ is not. The we try humanly $1$ with the Horner scheme,
$$
\begin{array}{r|rrrr}
&1 & 60 & 678 & -22321\\\hline
13 & 1 & 73 & 1717 & \boxed{0} 
\end{array}
$$
where the numbers in the second row are $1$, copied from above, $73=13\cdot 1+60$, $1717=13\cdot 73+678$, and finally $\boxed{0}=13\cdot 1717-22321$.

So one solution is $B=13$ and we have the factorization
$$ 
h(B):=
B^3 + 60B^2 + 768B - 22321 
=(B-13)(B^2+73B+1717)\ ,
$$
and the other two solutions are roots of $h(B)=0$ are the ones of 
$(B^2+73B+1717)=0$, explicitly $(-73\pm 9i\sqrt{19})/2$. To get the $A$ values, we multiply with two.

---

So far we have only one direction. For the other direction, we *check* that the obtained values lead to third roots that we can explicitly express.

$$
\begin{aligned}
(26\pm 15\sqrt 3)^{1/3}
&=
2\pm \sqrt 3\ ,
\\
(-73+9\sqrt{-19}\pm 15\sqrt 3)^{1/3}
&=
2 \mp \frac{\sqrt 3}2(1+\sqrt{-19})\ ,
\\
(-73-9\sqrt{-19}\pm 15\sqrt 3)^{1/3}
&=
2 \mp \frac{\sqrt 3}2(1-\sqrt{-19})\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
But in the case of using complex numbers, the third root is not "defined in the common sense", and the "two other choices" would break the equality.

Comment: My line is $$8(A^2-675)=(32-A)^3$$

Comment: OK, let us look for the other direction, so far we have only the fact that in case $A$ satisfies the given equation and it is real, then $A=26$. Now let us extract the third root explicitly. This third root is $2\pm \sqrt 3$. To see this with an easy typing, (they count my letters,) let $a$ be $\pm\sqrt 3$. Then: $$(2+a)^3=8+12a+6a^2+a^3=(8+18)+(12+3)a=26+15a\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=A-15\sqrt 3$ and $y=A+15\sqrt 3,$ then the equation becomes $$x^{1/3}+y^{1/3}=4.$$ Taking cubes of both sides gives $$x+y+3(xy)^{1/3}(x^{1/3}+y^{1/3})=4^3.$$ Now since $x+y=2A,$ and $x^{1/3}+y^{1/3}=4,$ the equation becomes $$2A+3(xy)^{1/3}(4)=4^3,$$ which gives $$6(xy)^{1/3}=32-A.$$ Now, cubing and substituting for $xy=A^2-15^2\cdot 3$ gives $$6^3(A^2-15^2\cdot 3)=(32-A)^3.$$ This is a cubic in $A,$ which in general is not so easy to deal with.

Comment: As a question of my exam, how could I solve this in final step using no calculator? I'll be thankful if you help:)

Comment: @BoshraAlef I don't know the level of the exam, but since it's an exam question it seems they wanted you to do something along the lines of what *rsadhvila* below did. Check his answer.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists a cubic polynomial of integer coefficients with roots:
$$0,\sqrt[3] {A-15√3} , \sqrt[3] {A+15√3} $$
then it will be of the form
$x^3-4x^2 + \sqrt[3]{A^2-675}x$

You just need to find $A$ such that $A^2-675$ is a perfect cube.
Trivially $A^2 = 676$ will do.

Comment: Thank you so much.I have a question: the form you wrote, where did it come from?

Comment: 1)  Since $x=0$ is a root, the constant term in the polynomial would be $0$. Constant term has to be $0$, other wise we cannot factor out $x$.

Comment: 2) Here sum of the roots is $4$, so the coefficient of $x^2$ would be $-4$

Comment: 3) Coefficient of $x$ can be obtained from the expression $$0\times \sqrt[3] {A-15√3} + \sqrt[3] {A-15√3}\times \sqrt[3] {A+15√3} + \sqrt[3] {A+15√3}\times 0$$

Comment: All that can be done in few seconds if you knew vieta : 
 https://brilliant.org/wiki/vietas-formula/  good luck:)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learnt so much:)

Comment: Np, you're welcome :D

Comment: I know I've asked too much so far, but how do we conclude that the coefficients are integer?

Comment: Well, the starting point has nothing to do with the given equation. In our case it is a **big coincidence** that the final solution works with $A=26$, and that the third root of $A\pm 15\sqrt 3=26\pm\sqrt 3$ is $2\pm \sqrt 3$, and that the polynomial with roots $(A\pm 15\sqrt 3)^{1/3}=2\pm\sqrt 3$ and any other integer, well your choice is zero for some unknown reason, has coefficients in $\Bbb Z$. Now we forget everything about the given equation, and impose this wish condition. An obvious solution is $26$, an other one is $5399/2704$, how do we know which is the good one?