# Given roots, does there exist a polynomial with "integer" coefficients?

Tags: polynomials

Given roots of form
$$a, ~~\sqrt[3]{b+c\sqrt{d}}, \sqrt[3]{b-c\sqrt{d}}$$
$a,b,c,d\in {\mathbb Z}$,
does there exist a cubic polynomial with integer coefficients with above roots?

---

I tried few examples and I seem to find a cubic polynomial every time XD
Is there a proof of this?

NOTE: I came across this while trying to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320229/find-a-in-this-equation) question.

Comment: If $b+c\sqrt d$ is a cube in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$....

Comment: Have you learned any field theory? This problem designed to be solved with tools of field theory.

Comment: Short answer: yes, as these are all algebraic. Take a polynomial that has the first as a root, multiply it by a polynomial with the second as a root, and multiply by another polynomial with the third as a root.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt How does that ensure integer coefficients...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm pretty sure OP is looking for integral polynomials.

Comment: Sorry, with the restriction of this being cubic the answer is no in general. But the above works to show you *can* construct such a polynomial.

Comment: A little bit, but not too much to be able to talk with you geniuses :) If I understand correctly, if we extend rationals using $\sqrt{d}$, we can find a cube root for $b+c\sqrt{d}$. This means finding a polynomial with integer coefficients only is not possible?

Comment: The product of the three future roots is not a rational number, thus there can't be a cubic with those three numbers as roots...

Comment: Oh right the product may not always be a perfect cube unless I force $a=0$; then $x$ factors out leaving just a quadratic with cube-root coefficients.. hmm

Comment: @DonThousand when $b+c\sqrt d$ is a cube in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$ then one will have a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

No, it should be at least a 6-th degree polynomial in general.

Let $(b,c,d)=(0,1,2)$.  What's the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[6]{2}$?

Comment: I haven't studied abstract algebra, but it seems $x^6-2$ ? I get it! Thank you so much :)